# Counting the number of leaves in a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an errors object in the following way and I want to count the total number of leaves, my object is as follows

I have tried using the object.keys() property but it only counts the direct children of the object and not the nested values

```
state = {
    driver: {
        user: {
            number: '1234',
            firstName: 'xyz',
            lastName: 'abc'
        },
        kyc: {
            name: 'kyc1',
            idNumber: 'kyc2'
        },
        license: {
            idNumber: '1234',
            issuedOn: '1991-05-12',
            validTill: '1991-12-12'
        }
    },
    vehicle: {
        vin: '4567',
        registrationNumber: '4567',
        dateBought: '1954-09-12',
        contractValidity: '1954-12-12',
        departments: [1, 2],
        vehicleType: 2
    },
    owner: {
        user: {
            number: '1234',
            firstName: 'lml',
            lastName: 'pqr',
            dateOfBirth: '2068-11-26'
        },
        kyc: {
            name: 'kyc2',
            idNumber: 'kyc123'
        },
        bank: {
            ifscCode: '1234',
            bankName: 'bank1',
            branchName: 'branch1',
            accountNumber: '1234',
            accountHolderName: 'holder1'
        },
        license: {
            idNumber: '12345',
            issuedOn: '1997-12-12',
            validTill: '1997-12-12'
        },
        insurance: {
            idNumber: '1234',
            issuedOn: '2909-12-12',
            validTill: '2909-12-12'
        }
    },
    errors: {},
    isSubmitable: false
}
```

Comment: Can you include an attempt so I can better understand what you are trying to do? Thanks

Comment: Would you consider an array to be one value or many?

Comment: @VLAZ an an array will never be a child object. so its a nested object with basic data types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a recursive approach and count each value that is not an object (but count arrays as a single leaf), otherwise get all values of the object and try to count them:

```js
const state = { driver: { user: { number: '1234', firstName: 'xyz', lastName: 'abc' }, kyc: { name: 'kyc1', idNumber: 'kyc2' }, license: { idNumber: '1234', issuedOn: '1991-05-12', validTill: '1991-12-12' } }, vehicle: { vin: '4567', registrationNumber: '4567', dateBought: '1954-09-12', contractValidity: '1954-12-12', departments: [1, 2], vehicleType: 2 }, owner: { user: { number: '1234', firstName: 'lml', lastName: 'pqr', dateOfBirth: '2068-11-26' }, kyc: { name: 'kyc2', idNumber: 'kyc123' }, bank: { ifscCode: '1234', bankName: 'bank1', branchName: 'branch1', accountNumber: '1234', accountHolderName: 'holder1' }, license: { idNumber: '12345', issuedOn: '1997-12-12', validTill: '1997-12-12' }, insurance: { idNumber: '1234', issuedOn: '2909-12-12', validTill: '2909-12-12' } }, errors: {}, isSubmitable: false}

function countLeaves(val) {
  if (typeof val !== "object" || Array.isArray(val)) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  return Object.values(val).map(countLeaves).reduce(sum, 0)
}

const sum = (a, b) => a + b;

console.log(countLeaves(state));
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on exactly how we define leaves, but something like this should work, using recursion:

```js
function countLeaves(obj) {
    return Object.values(obj).reduce((count,v) => count += (typeof(v) === 'object') ? countLeaves(v): 1, 0);
}

let state = { driver: { user: { number: '1234', firstName: 'xyz', lastName: 'abc' }, kyc: { name: 'kyc1', idNumber: 'kyc2' }, license: { idNumber: '1234', issuedOn: '1991-05-12', validTill: '1991-12-12' } }, vehicle: { vin: '4567', registrationNumber: '4567', dateBought: '1954-09-12', contractValidity: '1954-12-12', departments: [1, 2], vehicleType: 2 }, owner: { user: { number: '1234', firstName: 'lml', lastName: 'pqr', dateOfBirth: '2068-11-26' }, kyc: { name: 'kyc2', idNumber: 'kyc123' }, bank: { ifscCode: '1234', bankName: 'bank1', branchName: 'branch1', accountNumber: '1234', accountHolderName: 'holder1' }, license: { idNumber: '12345', issuedOn: '1997-12-12', validTill: '1997-12-12' }, insurance: { idNumber: '1234', issuedOn: '2909-12-12', validTill: '2909-12-12' } }, errors: {}, isSubmitable: false };

console.log("Number of leaves: ", countLeaves(state));
```

Comment: Just heads up - your solution returns `33` while mine returns `32`. I honestly don't know which is correct but since we do basically the same thing, the difference is that your solution counts each member of the array as a leaf. I'm not sure if that's OP's intention or not but it's at least good to show both are possible.

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, if we have an array of objects with each having its own object tree, presumably this should contribute to the total number of leaves. An array of values however shouldn't contribute.

Comment: Yeah, it's tricky. OP still hasn't come back to clarify, though. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks a lot your solution worked. highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let num = 0;
const objectLength = (obj) => {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (typeof value == 'object') {
            num++;
            objectLength(value);
        } else if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            num++;
        }
    }
}
```

This will count all elements, even the nested ones.